# SEO friendly URL htaccess Mod Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, cpanel

I currently have the below in my htaccess with removes the need for user to have '.php' after every page - for example going to URL.com/about works the same as URL.com/about.php:

```
Options -Indexes     
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f     
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

I also have a deals page where there are two variables in the URL:
`URL.com/deals?make=samsung&model=X500D`

What i would like to accomplish is for the above url to be accessed via:
`URL.com/samsung-X500D/`  (with the trailing sash to be optional)

I have tried adding the below to my existing htaccess code at the top but i get a 500 server error code:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ /deals?make=$1&model=$2 [L]
```

I also have no need to rewrite any css / img  files on the page - it is just the URL i want to change.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In general, it is agreed here that [you shouldn't use greetings or salutations in your posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276033/pointless-question-edit/276037#276037). They get in the way of us readers figuring out the actual question. I've edited them out for you this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure to use specific rewrite before catch-all PHP rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^-/]+)/?$ /deals?make=$1&model=$2 [L,QSA]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: In your `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]`, I don't understand the `$1`

Comment: $1 is the value being captured from RewriteRule as processing happens backwards in mod_rewrite. Did you test it?

Comment: I just read the documentation for RewriteCond, and it's Ok for $ and % thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)-(.+)$ deals.php?make=$1&model=$2 [L]
```